# How to exit from for loop with tryCatch at first warning?

Tags: r, for-loop, try-catch

I have a simple for loop from which I want to exit with *one* individual message once a warning occurs. I tried it with `tryCatch` like so:

```
for (i in 1:10) {        
  tryCatch({
    sqrt(-1)},
    warning = function(error_message) {
      message("My own warning message.")
      break})}
```

But this produces an error:

`Error in value[[3L]](cond) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level`

If I omit the `break`, I get ten warnings instead of only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to place the `break` function out of the `tryCatch`

```
for (i in 1:10) {        
  tryCatch({sqrt(-1)},
           warning = function(error_message) {
             message("My own warning message.")
             })
  break
  }
```

In this situation the error does not appear